# Как развернуть обьект при аггрегации MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongo

Мне нужно развернуть обьект чтобы:

```
[{
  data: {
    id: 1, 
    name: 'Test'
  }
}]
```

Стало:

```
[{
  id: 1, 
  name: 'Test'
}]
```

Обьекты везде разные и поля могут быть любыми так что перечисление через project не подойдет

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел ответ - $replaceRoot. Всем спасибо.